# Raspberry Pi as a PS3 controller

Tags: bluetooth, driver, modules

I want to make my raspberry pi to automate GT6 B-spec when I am away from my PS3 however, I cannot find a way how to get my raspberry pi to act as a PS3 controller (I have only found how to use my ps3 controller with my RPI).

Is there a way how to do this or not? If there isn't how would I sniff the bluetooth packets and clone them with my RPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could google, it looks like you have to write this yourself. However, check out the library published here: https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/wiki/PS3-Information. This is a library to allow connection of a PS3 controller to an Arduino using a shield, but it gives both details on the packets being sent/received as well as specific links to a more detailed explanation of the protocol, and bluetooth packet sniffer app suggestions (Mac and PC).

Specifically, it says:

> For information about the Bluetooth Protocol. See this pdf:
>   https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737
>
> Take a good look at the categories: "HCI COMMANDS AND EVENTS" Volume 2
>   p. 458, "HCI ACL Data Packets" Volume 2 p.428 and "SIGNALING PACKET
>   FORMATS" Volume 3 p. 54.
>
> See this [pdf](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=7108), for standard BT HID Commands, used by the program, at
>   "Bluetooth HID L2CAP Protocol Specification" p. 50.
>
> I used this program to sniff the Bluetooth Commands sent from my mac:
>   PacketLogger.app. It is developed by apple, so it is mac only! If you
>   are on a mac, this is what the program decoded:
>   PS3Controller_Protocol.pklg
>
> The Protocol and Service Multiplexor (PSM) used by the L2CAP Protocol
>   (HID_Control and HID_Interrupt), are defined here:
>   http://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/AssignedNumbers/logical_link.htm.

Comment: Thats good it's on a Mac since I only have a Mac and a RPI. I shall try it out in my spare time.